# How to use If statements in Laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display data in a view with if statements. However, in the if condition, else data (No data available) also appears, which should not appear.

```php
    <div class="dashboard-row-single">
          <div class="dashboard-body">
            <div class="font-demi type-paragraph1 big text-center">
              <span style="align-items:left; padding-right:10px;">
                <img src="/css/icons/custom-icon/inactive_trainer.svg" alt="Home" height="16" width="16">
              </span>
              Top 5 Trainer
            </div>
            <div>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal justify-content-center">
                @foreach($trainers as $train=>$ners)
                  @if($ners['sessions'] > 0)
                    <li class="list-group-item trainer-top-5">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                          @if($ners['picture'] != null)
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset($ners['picture']) }}">
                          @else
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('img/default_user.png') }}">
                          @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                          <div class="top-trainer-name">
                            <div class="type-paragraph2">{{$ners['uname']}}</div>
                            <div class="type-paragraph3">{{$ners['cname']}}</div>
                            <div class="top-trainer-session">{{$ners['sessions']}} Sessions</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  @else
                    No data available
                    @break
                  @endif
                @endforeach
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

How do we prevent data that should be in else from appearing in if?

Comment: why are you using `@break` after `@else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx all, this is solved with @forelse @empty @endforelse

Answer (score 0):

Get **Top 5 Trainer**, it mean `$trainers` get filter top(5) and order by sessions?

```
@if($ners['sessions'] > 0) //this check sessions so if sessions = 0 do else and @if($ners['picture'] != null) will be ignored
//some code
@else
 No data available
@break                     // this break end foreach so end your code
@endif
```

Your code is right but check `$trainers` data and this `@break`